# C++ If Else both statements executing when they shouldn't be

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to create a snake game in C++. Works for the most part however I'm trying to implement a cheat mode, when activated the snake shrinks to its original size and cannot lose the game from hitting walls etc. The problem I'm having though is that when the cheat key is pressed it is executing the "else if" correctly, but then also executing the "else" straight after. When pressing the arrow keys the else is skipped properly, It is only when the cheat key is pressed.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <cassert> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//constants
const int  UP(72);          //up arrow
const int  DOWN(80);        //down arrow
const int  RIGHT(77);       //right arrow
const int  LEFT(75);        //left arrow
const char QUIT('Q');       //to end the game
const char CHEAT('C');      //to activate cheat mode

int main()
{
    //protoypes
    bool isArrowKey(const int k);
    bool isCheatKey(const int k);
    bool wantsToQuit(const int k);
    int  getKeyPress();

    string message = "";

    //body
    system("CLS");
    int key;                                    //current key selected by player
    do {
        key = getKeyPress();                    //read in  selected key: arrow or letter command
        if (isArrowKey(key))
        {
        }
        else if (isCheatKey(key))
        {
            message = "cheat on";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "INVALID KEY!";           //set 'Invalid key' message
        }
    } while (!wantsToQuit(key));                //while user does not want to quit
    return 0;
}

// additional needed functions
int getKeyPress()
{ //get key or command selected by user
  //KEEP THIS FUNCTION AS GIVEN
    int keyPressed;
    keyPressed = _getch();          //read in the selected arrow key or command letter
    while (keyPressed == 224)       //ignore symbol following cursor key
        keyPressed = _getch();
    return keyPressed;
}

bool isArrowKey(const int key)
{  
    return (key == LEFT) || (key == RIGHT) || (key == UP) || (key == DOWN);
}

bool isCheatKey(const int key)
{   //check if the user wants to cheat (when key is 'C' or 'c')
    return toupper(key) == CHEAT;
}

bool wantsToQuit(const int key)
{   //check if the user wants to quit (when key is 'Q' or 'q')
    return toupper(key) == QUIT;
}
```

I expect the else to be skipped as it does when using the arrow keys but I cannot for the life of me work out why it is executing both statements. I'm sure the solution to this is quite simple but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function `wantsToQuit` is called in your loop condition but its source code is not included in your post. Please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: wantsToQuit just checks if the letter pressed is 'Q' and then returns true/false

Comment: Any way you can boil it down into a [mcve]?  Look okay as is.

Comment: I don't see how it does that. You will probably have to use a debugger. Start by setting breakpoints at `toggleCheatMode(gameItems, playerInfo, message);` and `message = "INVALID KEY!"; `

Comment: I've already set breakpoints at both of those that you have said. It first runs the toggleCheatMode() and then immediately goes into message = "Invalid Key"

Comment: That is weird. Looks like some type of Undefined Behavior. Are you sure that the current code compiled and you are not running an old binary?

Comment: Yea the current code compiles and runs perfectly fine. It's only the "else if" that seems to be playing up

Comment: Okay so I've edited the code provided to only show what is needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: You might want to print the value of key right after getting it in key = getKeyPress();  I suspect it's not that both sides of the if are executing, but that there are multiple iterations through the loop.  Or just put a break on that line as well as the sides of the if statement.

Comment: So I tried that and for some reason the key press is being reset to 0 after executing the "else if", unsure why. I originally tried using a break after but it exit out of the "do while" loop rather than just the "else if". Is there a way I can just make it exit the "else if"?

Comment: Please do what @Evan mentioned. I don't think it is executing the way you think. If it is something is very broken.

Comment: I did do what @Evan said, but I don't think I explained myself properly. It is actually looping twice, the first time the key has the correct value and the code is executed correctly, but then it goes through again but sets the key value to 0 rather than asking for an input again, and I'm unsure why

Comment: Now that makes some sense. I can't help you with the `_getch()` problem. I have not used that in the last 25 years as a `c++` programmer.

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and see what is actually happening.

Comment: Also, since the arrow key codes overlap letter key codes your getKeyPress function is absolutely begging for trouble!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by replacing _getch() with _getwch(). Apparently _getwch() can return more distinct values so it seemed to solve the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

In your main do while, you have an if else loop of 3 possible conditions. 1, the key is a control key. 2, the key is a cheat key. 3, otherwise. On the last else you do not check if it is a quit key or not, so on quit keys "Invalid Key" is always printed.